# Whats wrong with passing a complex type as a result in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, c++-cli, managed-c++

I've got following WCF methods:

```
[OperationContract]
array<Object^>^ GetResult(UInt64 taskId);

[OperationContract]
array<UrlInfo^>^ GetResultAsUriInfo(UInt64 taskId);
```

when I do return array of strings through GetResult, it works fine. Also, when I return array of UrlInfo through GetResultAsUriInfo it works without any problems. However, when I'm trying to return appay of UrlInfo through GetResult, I'm getting following client side exception:

```
 The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be  
 used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
```

the inner exception is null.

Here's the definition for UrlInfo:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class UrlInfo
{
    Uri uri;

    [DataMember]
    public Uri Uri
    {
        get { return uri; }
        set { uri = value; }
    }
    string title;

    [DataMember]
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    string description;
    [DataMember]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }

    List<string> tags = new List<string>();
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Tags
    {
        get { return tags; }
        set { tags = value; }
    }

    Dictionary<string, string> allMetadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, string> AllMetadata
    {
        get { return allMetadata; }
        set { allMetadata = value; }
    }


    string[] categoryPreferences = new string[0];

    [DataMember]
    public string[] CategoryPreferences
    {
        get { return categoryPreferences; }
        set { categoryPreferences = value; }
    }
```

Why can't I return an array of UrlInfo as array of objects?

Comment: Can you post some code that shows on how you are trying to return array of urlinfo as array of objects?

Answer (score 2):

wcf can just pass knowntypes and not generic types - but i m not familiar with c++ syntax.

but you can write your own serializer for your types if you need.

EDIT: i really should read the question more carefully. the problem is your object type in

```
 array<Object^>^ GetResult(UInt64 taskId);
```

object type can't be serialized in WCF. you should ues the type you expect there.

Comment: what is the ^ in your array<UrlInfo^>^ GetResultAsUriInfo(UInt64 taskId);?

Comment: frankly, I don't know, but cli c++ won't create managed types without this thing))